# How to create a SPUser object from its XML representation

Tags: object-model, xml, spuser, user

I have the following XML representation for a user:

```
  <pc:Person xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls">
    <pc:DisplayName>John Dodo</pc:DisplayName>
    <pc:AccountId>DOMAIN\john.dodo</pc:AccountId>
    <pc:AccountType>User</pc:AccountType>
  </pc:Person>
```

**How can I convert this to a `SPUser` object?**

I don't want to parse the XML for this so I guess there is a standard way to do it but could not find how.

(I'm using SharePoint 2010 if that counts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you will have to parse the XML.  Its very easy to do

```
        string xml = @"<pc:Person xmlns:pc=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls""> 
                        <pc:DisplayName>John Dodo</pc:DisplayName> 
                        <pc:AccountId>DOMAIN\john.dodo</pc:AccountId> 
                        <pc:AccountType>User</pc:AccountType> 
                       </pc:Person>";

        var ns = "{http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls}";

        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        var loginName = doc.Descendants(ns + "AccountId").FirstOrDefault().Value;

        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://SiteCollectionURL"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPUser user = web.AllUsers[loginName];
            }
        }
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid this. The XML string is not visible (it comes from a variable) and didn't want to parse it because the code is not very clear on what's working. I would have to add a sample XML in some comments etc. I wanted something like `SPUser.LoadFrom(string)` but couldn't find a thing.

Comment: I don't think there is anything in the SharePoint API that will do that for you.  Your going to have to write code to do it.  The SPUser class doesn't have any constructors or static methods that return an SPUser.  See the [SPUser Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms456617.aspx) for your options to get SPUser objects.

Comment: Couldn't find a way to "load" the XML into an instance so I eventually parsed the XML for the data I was interested in.